# Treat Comma and Period as Decimal Separator in Navision Decimal Fields

Tags: dynamics-nav

I want to eliminate an error source, often happening in our company. In our country, we use the comma as decimal separator and a valid decimal number looks something like this: `85,32`

The problem is, that the users sometimes press the period instead of the comma, because the keys are next to each other on the keyboard and they do not recognize their mistakes. Navision now formats the number entered `85.32` to `8.532,00` what leads to wrong data in our database.

I tried to set the *AutoFormatType* to `10` and the *AutoFormatExpr* to something like this `<Integer><Point or Comma><Decimals>` and I played around with some other values for *AutoFormatExpr*, but it still does not recognize the period as a valid comma separator. I even tried to format it afterwards at the OnValidate-trigger, but the *AutoFormat* logics of navision seems to come first and the value is already altered before the OnValidate field triggers gets executed.

I want to setup my page (or a specific decimal field in particular) that, no matter if the user types `85,33` or `85.33`, the result should be `85,33`.

Comment: Version of Nav? Which number format is set in system settings (windows settings)? Have you tried to change system-wide number format?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I wrote the NAV Version. It's Dynamics NAV 2009 RTC. The field is a decimal field and the System wide options are set to comma for decimal separation and point for thousand separation. e.g. 1.087,54. But I want to specifically disable the system wide settings for this particular field to allow comma AND point as decimal separation.

Comment: Substitution way. Create a field on form(page) with SourceExpr of string type then parse it to whatever you like decimal format and save it to the real field. But honestly... just change system settings.

Comment: Yes, I guess I will do it that way. I am afraid I can not change the settings system wide because the comma is default in the system and default for the country here, so the system settings are correct (in that way). However even if I would change the system settings from comma to perdiod than the problem would not be soved because some user would then accidently press the comma instead of the period (or vise versa), so I guess I have to live with it and use for specific fields the Text-datatype way and parsing the value by c/al code. thank you :)

Comment: I'll post it as answer then, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitution way. Create a field on form(page) with SourceExpr of string type then parse it to whatever you like decimal format and save it to the real field.